# Are `touse' and `varlist' reserved names for locals?

Tags: stata

What do `touse` and `varlist` mean exactly? Are these locals generated automatically?

```
program sample, sortpreserve rclass 

syntax varname(numeric) [fweight] [if] [in] ///

if "`summarize'" != "" local summ "summ" 
if "`welfare'" != ""    local w "w" 
local inc "`varlist'"

if "`weight'" == "" gen byte `wi' = 1
else gen `wi' `exp'

marksample touse
if "`bygroup'" != "" markout `touse' `bygroup'

qui count if `touse'
if r(N) == 0 error 2000
```

Comment: For the record, the code here is a program fragment that couldn't work.

Comment: I shortened the `syntax` line. Is it the reason it would not work?

Comment: No; there are several other reasons why it not would work. You refer to local macros that are never defined; you define macros that are never used. There is no `end` statement. That's unlikely to be a complete list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither is a reserved word, but in both cases there are conventional uses.

Using the name `touse` in conjunction with `marksample` started as a convention in so far as StataCorp programmers use it as house style and many user-programmers followed suit. (The name runs together "to use".)

What `marksample touse` does, usually but not necessarily after a `syntax` statement, is to create a byte indicator variable which is 1 in observations to be used by a command and 0 in observations not to be used.

However, it is a very good convention. Whether you adopt it depends partly on whether you want your Stata programs to be understood by other Stata programmers. Nothing stops you using another name, which you would then need to use later in your programs.

Using the name `varlist` splits into two. Your example program shows the first, but not the second.

- If a `syntax` statement specifies `varname` or `varlist` indicating that variables may be specified (and often how many and what kind), then once that is executed the name(s) of the variables in question will be held in a local macro `varlist`, which can be thought  of as created by `syntax`.
- You can always use the macro name `varlist` for any purpose you like, although it would be considered poor style to do that for anything but a list of variable names. So, you can always go (e.g.)

  ```
  local varlist "mpg weight"
  ```

Note that if `syntax` earlier created such a `varlist` macro, then any such definition will overwrite it, a source of strange bugs if that is not what you want. (The same applies e.g. to local macros `if` and `in`.)

Answer (score 6):

The local `varlist` was created by the `syntax` command, and contains the name of a single variable (as you specified `varname` not `varlist`). You can read more about this here: http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?syntax

The temporary variable `touse` was created by the command `marksample touse`. It is a variable that is 1 when `varlist` and any weight variable is not missing and the `if` and `in` conditions are satisfied, and 0 otherwise. You later modify that variable using `markout` to have value 0 when the variable(s) in `bygroup` are missing. In essence it is a temporary variable that contains the value 1 (true) when you want to use that observation and 0 (false) when you want to ignore that observation. You can read more about that here: http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?marksample

Comment: As the `marksample` help explains, `marksample` can be used ignoring a varlist, which you would typically do if you didn't want to filter out missing values.